# Alternative to abbrev-mode that supports special characters in abbreviations?

Tags: abbrev

I already use `abbrev-mode` to correct common typos, e.g. I have an abbrev setup for expanding `functino` to `function`, etc...

I'm currently writing a large document, and I keep stumbling over the decision whether to write "lifecycle" or "life-cycle", I decided to go with the former and add an abbreviation for "life-cycle" which would autocorrect it to "lifecycle". However, `abbrev-mode` is not able to expand over the `-` there and from what I understand there's no way to make `abbrev-mode` understand that.

Are there any alternatives out there that will make things like this work?

Comment: Why don't you use `(query-replace-regexp "\\<life-cycle\\>" "lifecycle")`? If you want to stick to `abbrev-mode` you could modify the syntax entry of `-` to word-constituent, i.e., `"w"`, with the help of `modify-syntax-entry`.

Comment: Well I don't want to replace all of the words after the fact, I want it to be immediate in order to prevent the problem altogether. I used to be able to do this in vim with abbreviations pretty easily.
I'd rather not modify the syntax-entry for `-` because it would interfere with movement. Is there no alternative?

Comment: You do not need to modify the syntax table permanently. Just modify it temporarily while abbreviation takes place. I've demonstrated this in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue to use `abbrev-mode`.
The following elisp snippet allows you to specify additional characters as word-consistent when abbreviation takes place.

After running the snippet customize the option `abbrev-additional-chars` with an alist that maps major-mode symbols to the lists of characters that should be interpreted as word-consistent during abbreviation.

The special mode symbol `t` corresponds to additional characters active in all modes.

The default value of `abbrev-additional-chars` is `'((t ?-))` which covers your use-case.

You can install the snippet in your init file if you like.

```el
(defcustom abbrev-additional-chars
  '((t ?-))
  "Alist that maps major mode symbols to lists of characters that may appear in abbreviations.
The chars of the special major mode symbol `t' are active in all modes."
  :group 'abbrev
  :type '(repeat :tag "List of modes"
                 (cons :tag "Map major mode symbols to lists of additional chars in abbrevs"
                       (symbol :tag "Mode symbol (`t' stands for all modes)")
                       (repeat :tag "List of additional word-consistent characters" character))))

(defvar-local T-abbrev-syntax-table nil
  "List of additional characters in abbreviations.")

(defun T-abbrev-mode-hook-fun ()
  "Populate T-abbrev-syntax-table with the local syntax table modfied by
the characters in `abbrev-additional-chars'."
  (when abbrev-mode
    (let ((char-list (append (cdr (assoc major-mode abbrev-additional-chars))
                             (cdr (assoc 't abbrev-additional-chars)))))
      (setq T-abbrev-syntax-table (make-syntax-table (syntax-table)))
      (mapcar (lambda (char)
                (modify-syntax-entry char "w" T-abbrev-syntax-table))
              char-list))))

;; Wrapping functions of the `abbrev` package with the local syntax table.
;; I'm not sure I captured all fun's that need to run with the local syntax-table.
;; Adding further functions is easy.
;; Just add them to the list at the end of the next form.
(mapcar
 (lambda (fun)
   (let ((newfun (intern (concat "T-ad-" (symbol-name fun)))))
     (eval
      `(progn
         (defun ,newfun (oldfun &rest args)
           ,(concat "This function evaluates `" (symbol-name fun) "' with `T-abbrev-syntax-table' as active syntax table.
It is used for the advicing `" (symbol-name fun) "'.")
           (with-syntax-table T-abbrev-syntax-table
             (apply oldfun args)
             ))
         (advice-add (quote ,fun) :around (quote ,newfun))))))
 '(define-mode-abbrev abbrev--before-point))

(add-hook 'abbrev-mode-hook #'T-abbrev-mode-hook-fun)
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to be just what I was looking for, however it seems to break a couple of things: When I try to type non-word characters in the minibuffer, I now get an error: `(wrong-type-argument syntax-table-p nil)`

Comment: I was able to make it work after some tinkering by wrapping the `with-syntax-table` call in an if to check whther or not `T-abbrev-syntax-table` is actually set.

Comment: @DeX3 I cannot reproduce the problem with the undefined syntax table in emacs 25.1.50.2. Could you give a receipt for error reproduction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DeX3 Now I had the same error in a buffer with a major-mode basing on `c-mode`. I had a look at `c-mode`. It is actually not my fault that things go wrong. The problem is that they directly use `(setq abbrev-mode t)` in `c-mode`. Even the doc string of variable `abbrev-mode` says `Use the command ‘abbrev-mode’ to change this variable.`! But, it is clear that we have to handle this problem on our side. I will think about it.

Comment: @DeX3 Note, that I filed a bug-report for `c-mode`.

Comment: This does not seem to work if the abbreviation finishes on a special character. For example, with this `(setq abbrev-additional-chars '((t ?[ ?])))`, `[d` triggers an abbreviation if defined, but `d[` does not. (And hence neither does `[d]`)

Comment: @Tobias I copied the code but got the error DeX3 was talking about, so I put an if around the three lines starting with `with-syntax-table` that asks for `T-abbrev-syntax-table `, now I don't get an error but my abbrevs don't get expanded at all, even if I use `C-x a e`.